# Csv Jdbc : ResultSet.getRow() unsupported

Tags: java, jdbc, csv

How do I enable ResultSet.getRow() in CsvJdbc?

(this is a function that is supposed to return the current row number)

It appears to be dependent on an `isScrollable` member. If anyone has encountered this before, how do you work around it?

- Is it a property I need to set in the `Properties` object passed in?
- Would I need to "sanitize" or somehow modify my CSV files in any way?

Thanks!

---

**More Info**

An application I use has the capability of importing data from any JDBC source. I need to get some data from CSV files into it, hence I'm using CsvJdbc. This application needs to access the row numbers of each line of data it imports, and unfortunately CsvResultSet#getRow() throws an exception, complaining that "Csv Jdbc : ResultSet.getRow() unsupported".

The following is the impl. of the `getRow()` method in CsvJdbc (1.0.5)

```
/**
 * Retrieves the current row number.  The first row is number 1, the
 * second number 2, and so on.
 *
 * @return the current row number; <code>0</code> if there is no current row
 * @exception SQLException if a database access error occurs
 */
public int getRow() throws SQLException {
    if (this.isScrollable == ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE) {
        return currentRow;
    } else {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "ResultSet.getRow() unsupported");
    }
}
```

Looking through the rest of the source it seems that the only place that the `isScrollable` member property is set is in the constructor and as a default value.

Comment: I've been researching SQL querying on CSVs.. did CsvJdbc satisfy the usual SQL requirements (e.g. `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY`, `JOIN` etc.)? If not, which did you use to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried creating a scrollable statement...

Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);